# React-native : TypeError : Undefined is not a function (this.state.albums.map)

Tags: react-native

I got this error when I'm trying to run it with genymotion as my emulator. Here is my code

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Axios from 'axios';

class AlbumList extends Component {
 state={ albums: {} };


   componentWillMount() {
   Axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
    .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
  }
   renderAlbums() {
   this.state.albums.map(album => <Text> { album.title } </Text>);
}

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
        <View>
            {this.renderAlbums()}
        </View>
    );
  }
}  



export default AlbumList;
```

am i missing something? if anyone could help me with this please let me know, i'm stuck on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initially set state.albums to an empty object but you try to invoke map which is an array method.

Also make sure that the response.data from your api is an array.

It is best practice to initialize the state in the constructor.

```
class AlbumList extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
           super(props);
           this.state={
                albums: []
           }; 
      }
      ...
 }
```

Comment: No. {} initializes an object and [] initializes an array. In JS everything besides primitive types is an object. An array is merely an object with a few more functions (like map).